# Sphere inside a conical vessel touches the lid

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

A conical vessel with semi-vertical angle 30 degrees and height 10.5 cm has a thin lid. A sphere kept in the vessel touches the lid. The radius of the sphere in cm is ...

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Look at it from the side - you have a circle inscribed in an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It reveals the centre of the circle acts as orthocentre, then use the ratio 2:1 for the height.You got the radius is 3.5cm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).