# to find the radius of the sphere

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

[image: 1]

I tried like: here slant height $l={h\over\sin 60}$ and radius of the base of the cone $R=h\tan 60$ but I am not able to find the radius of the sphere.

Comment: If the "semi-vertical" angle is the one between the cone's axis and the slant side, then I think it should be $\;R=h\tan 30^\circ=3.5\sqrt3\cong 6.06\;$...but this doesn't appear as option so I guess that angle is something else...and $\;h=10.5\;$ , isn't it?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/426415/264